# Routing Key logic

Tags: lora, orange-api

For the Orange Live Objects, I want to "filter" the messages coming from a certain "profile" and sends them to a MQTT queue.

For messages with another profile, I would like to send them to a different MQTT queue.

It seems that I can use the Routing Key logic for this, although all examples are based on DevEUI as example (a single sensor) and not on a sensor type (which makes much more sense as you would like to decode your messages per sensor_type iso sensor.

Has anyone already tried if the Routing Key could work with selecting on "profile" level?

Answer (score 0):

for now it's not possible, but with the new version of Live Objects announced for next july, it will be possible to build groups of Lora devices and route corresponding messages in different queues